# Yahoo! emails lost

Tags: yahoo-mail

I was sent two emails to my Yahoo! account. I have checked all the folders in my Yahoo! email but have not found the emails. I know it was sent to the right email address because it had a bcc to my friend's email. How could this happen?

Comment: How long ago was it sent and how long after did your friend receive it?  We're going to need more information to answer the question effectively.

Comment: it was sent 3 months ago. They received it as soon as it was sent...

Comment: My friend is on hotmail.